# Is there an intuitive way to understand the Lagrangian for magnetic and electric dipole moment?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-matrices, dipole-moment

From the textbook I learned that the electric dipole moment (EDM) and magnetic dipole moment (MDM) has the following Lagrangian:

$$\mathcal{L}_{EDM}=F_{\nu\mu}\bar{\psi}\gamma^{5}\left[  \gamma^{\nu},\gamma^{\mu}\right]\psi\\
\mathcal{L}_{MDM}=iF_{\nu\mu}\bar{\psi}\left[  \gamma^{\nu},\gamma^{\mu}\right]\psi$$

However, to see they truly produce EDM and MDM respectively, I have to resort to brute force by expanding everything and go to the non-relativistic limit in the Dirac representation of Gamma matrices.

I wonder if there is a way to determine which is which without calculation, or better, an intuition that leads someone to write out these two Lagrangians for MDM and EDM out of nowhere.

Comment: Related: [how could the effective electric dipole interaction be derived?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167308/)

Comment: Might be useful for building some intuition: if you approximate the dipoles as point elements (i.e., not a rigorous quantum mechanical regime), the QED interaction term $-A^{\mu}J_{\mu}$ provides the known classical result for the potential energy of dipoles in external fields.

Comment: *an intuition that leads someone to write out these two Lagrangians for MDM and EDM out of nowhere* The set of Dirac bilinears is very limited, and that commutator is the spin operator.

Comment: @Ghoster I understand that the commutator is the Lorentz generator, thus related to spin. But how should I know why the one with $\Gamma^5$ is the one for EDM

Comment: @LPZ, thx but the answer here is by brute force, not what I'm looking for.

Comment: *How should I know why the one with $\Gamma^5$ is the one for EDM?* I’m not sure. Possibly using some argument involving C, P, and/or T invariance.